# How can I rotate the character in String at specific point?

Tags: java

I can write a code like this which can only rotate the character before m and M after n and N

```
public class solution {
    public static String encode(String s) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);

            if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'm' || c >= 'A' && c <= 'M') {
                sb.append((char) ((int) c + 13));
                continue;
            }

            if (c >= 'n' && c <= 'z' || c >= 'N' && c <= 'Z') {
                sb.append((char) ((int) c - 13));
                continue;
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(encode("firefly"));
    }
}
```

so how can I adjust it to in put a string also a integer `public static String encode(String s, int i)` so that i will rotate from the number i in the 26 character. For example, If I input 12 as int, then it will no longer rotate started from m or M, but it will rotate from l or L. that is seem like way harder than do it at very middle of the 26 characters.

Comment: Use modulus math: `%`. Also, see [Caesar cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).

Comment: This is almost exactly what a Caesar cipher is. Please do more research!

Answer (score 1):

for lower case characters you want code like:

```
int before = c - 'a';
int after = (before + i) % 26;
sb.append((char)('a'+(char)after));
```

The code for upper case characters is pretty similar.